# how to add runOnUiThread() in my Activity

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-asynctask

I added the AsyncTask to offload network operations to a background thread.I need to make sure the UI operations are on the UI thread.So i want to Use runOnUiThread() in my Activity.

Thanks for your help

**WifiApManager**

```
public class WifiApManager {
private final WifiManager mWifiManager;

public WifiApManager(Context context) {
    mWifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
}

public boolean setWifiApEnabled(WifiConfiguration wifiConfig, boolean enabled) {
    try {
        if (enabled) { // disable WiFi in any case
            mWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
        }

        Method method = mWifiManager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);
        return (Boolean) method.invoke(mWifiManager, wifiConfig, enabled);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "wifi", e);
        return false;
    }
}

public WIFI_AP_STATE getWifiApState() {
    try {
        Method method = mWifiManager.getClass().getMethod("getWifiApState");

        int tmp = ((Integer)method.invoke(mWifiManager));

        // Fix for Android 4
        if (tmp > 10) {
            tmp = tmp - 10;
        }

        return WIFI_AP_STATE.class.getEnumConstants()[tmp];
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "wifi", e);
        return WIFI_AP_STATE.WIFI_AP_STATE_FAILED;
    }
}


public boolean isWifiApEnabled() {
    return getWifiApState() == WIFI_AP_STATE.WIFI_AP_STATE_ENABLED;
}


public WifiConfiguration getWifiApConfiguration() {
    try {
        Method method = mWifiManager.getClass().getMethod("getWifiApConfiguration");
        return (WifiConfiguration) method.invoke(mWifiManager);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "wifi", e);
        return null;
    }
}


public boolean setWifiApConfiguration(WifiConfiguration wifiConfig) {
    try {
        Method method = mWifiManager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApConfiguration", WifiConfiguration.class);
        return (Boolean) method.invoke(mWifiManager, wifiConfig);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "wifi", e);
        return false;
    }
}


public ArrayList<ClientScanResult> getClientList(boolean onlyReachables) {
    return getClientList(onlyReachables, 10);
}


public ArrayList<ClientScanResult> getClientList(boolean onlyReachables, int reachableTimeout) {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    ArrayList<ClientScanResult> result = null;

    try {
        result = new ArrayList<ClientScanResult>();
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] splitted = line.split(" +");

            if ((splitted != null) && (splitted.length >= 4)) {
                // Basic sanity check
                String mac = splitted[3];

                if (mac.matches("..:..:..:..:..:..")) {
                    boolean isReachable = InetAddress.getByName(splitted[0]).isReachable(reachableTimeout);

                    if (!onlyReachables || isReachable) {
                        result.add(new ClientScanResult(splitted[0], splitted[3], splitted[5], isReachable));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, e.toString());
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOGTAG, e.toString());
        }
    }
return result;
}
}
```

**connect.java**

```
public class connect extends Activity{
WifiApManager wifiApManager;
TextView tv;
Button scan;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.connect);
    tv =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.iptv);
    new scan().execute();
}
public class scan extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

public Object WIFI_SERVICE;
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...integers)  {
     ArrayList<ClientScanResult> clients = wifiApManager.getClientList(false);
        tv.setText("WifiApState: " + wifiApManager.getWifiApState() + "\n\n");
        tv.append("Clients: \n");
        for (ClientScanResult clientScanResult : clients) {
            tv.append("####################\n");
            tv.append("IpAddr: " + clientScanResult.getIpAddr() + "\n");
            tv.append("Device: " + clientScanResult.getDevice() + "\n");
            tv.append("HWAddr: " + clientScanResult.getHWAddr() + "\n");
            tv.append("isReachable: " + clientScanResult.isReachable()+ "\n");
            }
}
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            tv.setText(result);             
        }
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    wifiApManager = new WifiApManager(this);
    // the above line shows a Error
    return null;
}
}
}
```

**EDIT**

I want to Display the processed text in a TextView

```
class scan extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> { 
public Context context;
ArrayList<ClientScanResult> clients;
public scan(Context c)  // constructor to take Context
{
    context = c;   // Initialize your Context variable
}

protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        wifiApManager = new WifiApManager(context);  // use the variable here
         clients = wifiApManager.getClientList(false);
        return null;
}
}           
protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
    ArrayList<ClientScanResult> clients;
    tv.setText("WifiApState: " + wifiApManager.getWifiApState() + "\n\n");
    tv.append("Clients: \n");
    for (ClientScanResult clientScanResult : clients)//showin error in clients
 {
            tv.append("####################\n");
            tv.append("IpAddr: " + clientScanResult.getIpAddr() + "\n");
            tv.append("Device: " + clientScanResult.getDevice() + "\n");
            tv.append("HWAddr: " + clientScanResult.getHWAddr() + "\n");
            tv.append("isReachable: " + clientScanResult.isReachable()+ "\n");
                       }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I added the AsyncTask to offload network operations to a background thread.I need to make sure the UI operations are on the UI thread.So i want to Use runOnUiThread() in my Activity.

Ugh! No!!! **Every** method of `AsyncTask` runs on the `UI Thread` except for `doInBackground()`. So do your network operations in `doInBackground()` and update the `UI` in `onPostExecute()` or in `onProgressUpdate()` by calling `publishProgress()` from `doInBackground()`.

Do not use `runOnUiThread()` with `AsyncTask`. There is no reason, at least known to me, to use that with `AsyncTask` since it has methods that already run on the `UI Thread`. I have never seen it do anything but cause trouble.

You can either call `publishProgress()` from your `loop` and update your `TextView` in `onProgressUpdate()` or add the values to an `ArrayList` and update in `onProgressUpdate()`.

[Please read the docs several times](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). `AsyncTask` is a bit tricky at first but once you learn what it does then it can be a beautiful thing.

**Edit**

Create an instance of your `AsyncTask` and pass your `Activity Context` to it

```
Scan myScan = new scan(this); // pass the context to the constructor
myScan.execute();
```

Then create a constructor in your `AsyncTask` and have it accept a `Context`.

```
public class scan extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> 
{

     public Object WIFI_SERVICE;
     public Context context;   // Context variable

     public scan(Context c)  // constructor to take Context
     {
         context = c;   // intialize your Context variable
     }
```

Now use that variable

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
        wifiApManager = new WifiApManager(context);  // use the variable here
        return null;
    }
```

**Another Edit**

```
class scan extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
     ArrayList<ClientScanResult> clients;
     Context context;

...

then initialize your `clients` in `doInBackground()`

clients = wifiApManager.getClientList(false);
```

change `onPostExecute()` to not accept anything

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
```

and put your code that updates the `TextView` in there.

Comment: Error on doInBackground.Need help

Comment: `this` will refer to the `AsyncTask` in this situation. You need to pass a `Context` to the `AsyncTask` via a `constructor`. And please don't change your original post or it will be useless and confusing to others. You can update the question to include the changes though

Comment: Ok, I can't possibly help you without knowing what that error is. Also, if you want help then you should consider accepting answers that help you by clicking the check mark next to them

Comment: Ok, then you didn't declare the variable as I showed in my edit.

Comment: No errors but the textview is not showing.There is a Mistake in the Asynctask.

Comment: You aren't returning anything from `doInBackground()` to `onPostExecute()` so `result` wouldn't have a value.

Comment: See my edit. You will also have to take `setText()` out of `onPostExecute()` or it will override the text you have appended. You could also search for the clients in `doInBackground()` then just put the code from `onProgressUpdate()` in `onPostExecute()` which would make more sense since you aren't updating intermittenly

Comment: See my edit again. You don't need `onProgressUpdate()`. Do **all** of your network processing in `doInBackground()` then update the `TextView` in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Remove `ArrayList<ClientScanResult> clients;` from `onPostExecute()`

Comment: I'm not sure then. If you have it declared as a class variable with `context` then it should work. Declaring it again in `onPostExecute()` makes it a local variable and it won't be populated.

Comment: Got Cleared ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845369/how-to-troubleshoot-asynctask/

Answer (score 0):

You should not be accessing any UI elements within `doInBackground`, This method runs in background thread. What you should do is override `onPostExecute()` method and access your `TextView` there. `onPostExecute` runs in UI thread, so you don't need to call `runOnUiThread()`