# How to Troubleshoot Asynctask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, wifimanager

My App shows a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` in the Log Cat.
So I found the Asynctask Method to offload network operations to a background thread.
After adding the AsyncTask.It shows `ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException`.So i have to use `onPostExecute`.
I learnt the `Asyntack` Docs & tried.Now i got Stuck it is not Returning the correct output.I don't know whether i declared it under the respective Method's.

I want to display the processed Text  in the `Textview` tv

So Help me in the Right Direction :)

Thanks for your Help ...

**WifiApManager**

```
public class WifiApManager {
     private final WifiManager mWifiManager;

public WifiApManager(Context context) {
    mWifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
}

public boolean setWifiApEnabled(WifiConfiguration wifiConfig, boolean enabled) {
    try {
        if (enabled) { // disable WiFi in any case
            mWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
        }

        Method method = mWifiManager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);
        return (Boolean) method.invoke(mWifiManager, wifiConfig, enabled);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "wifi", e);
        return false;
    }
}

public WIFI_AP_STATE getWifiApState() {
    try {
        Method method = mWifiManager.getClass().getMethod("getWifiApState");

        int tmp = ((Integer)method.invoke(mWifiManager));

        // Fix for Android 4
        if (tmp > 10) {
            tmp = tmp - 10;
        }

        return WIFI_AP_STATE.class.getEnumConstants()[tmp];
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "wifi", e);
        return WIFI_AP_STATE.WIFI_AP_STATE_FAILED;
    }
}


public boolean isWifiApEnabled() {
    return getWifiApState() == WIFI_AP_STATE.WIFI_AP_STATE_ENABLED;
}


public WifiConfiguration getWifiApConfiguration() {
    try {
        Method method = mWifiManager.getClass().getMethod("getWifiApConfiguration");
        return (WifiConfiguration) method.invoke(mWifiManager);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "wifi", e);
        return null;
    }
}


public boolean setWifiApConfiguration(WifiConfiguration wifiConfig) {
    try {
        Method method = mWifiManager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApConfiguration", WifiConfiguration.class);
        return (Boolean) method.invoke(mWifiManager, wifiConfig);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "wifi", e);
        return false;
    }
}


public ArrayList<ClientScanResult> getClientList(boolean onlyReachables) {
    return getClientList(onlyReachables, 10);
}


public ArrayList<ClientScanResult> getClientList(boolean onlyReachables, int reachableTimeout) {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    ArrayList<ClientScanResult> result = null;

    try {
        result = new ArrayList<ClientScanResult>();
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] splitted = line.split(" +");

            if ((splitted != null) && (splitted.length >= 4)) {
                // Basic sanity check
                String mac = splitted[3];

                if (mac.matches("..:..:..:..:..:..")) {
                    boolean isReachable = InetAddress.getByName(splitted[0]).isReachable(reachableTimeout);

                    if (!onlyReachables || isReachable) {
                        result.add(new ClientScanResult(splitted[0], splitted[3], splitted[5], isReachable));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, e.toString());
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOGTAG, e.toString());
        }
    }
return result;
}
}
```

**connect.java**

```
public class connect extends Activity{
WifiApManager wifiApManager;
TextView tv;
Button scan;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.connect);
    tv =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.iptv);
scan myScan = new scan(this); // pass the context to the constructor
    myScan.execute();
}
class scan extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> { 
    public Context context;
    ArrayList<ClientScanResult> clients;
    public scan(Context c)  // constructor to take Context
    {
        context = c;   // Initialize your Context variable
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            wifiApManager = new WifiApManager(context);  // use the variable here
             clients = wifiApManager.getClientList(false);
            return null;
    }
    }           
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        ArrayList<ClientScanResult> clients;
        tv.setText("WifiApState: " + wifiApManager.getWifiApState() + "\n\n");
        tv.append("Clients: \n");
for (ClientScanResult clientScanResult : clients) //showin error in clients
     {
                tv.append("####################\n");
                tv.append("IpAddr: " + clientScanResult.getIpAddr() + "\n");
                tv.append("Device: " + clientScanResult.getDevice() + "\n");
                tv.append("HWAddr: " + clientScanResult.getHWAddr() + "\n");
                tv.append("isReachable: " + clientScanResult.isReachable()+ "\n");
                           }
    }
    }
```

**Note:**
It shows a error in connect.java on onPostExecute Method in Clients Variable.

Comment: did you use the debugger to step through your code and see at which line it fails at?

Comment: why is there a 'clients' as a class member and as a local variable in onPostExecute?

Comment: You've defined a 'clients' variable again in onPostExecute that isn't instantiated. I'm guessing you get a NPE when you iterate it. Try commenting it out. If that doesn't fix it post your logcat so we can see the error you are getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your onPostExecute(...) you have

```
ArrayList<ClientScanResult> **clients**;
```

and then

```
for (ClientScanResult clientScanResult : **clients**) //showin error in clients
```

clients is null therefore the loop is never executed. you don't need to define a new ArrayList since you already have one defined as a global variable in the scan class

A better way to do this is to set the return type of doInBackground to ArrayList< ClientScanResult> and then you have onPostExecute take an ArrayList< ClientScanResult>

```
class scan extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<ClientScanResult>> { 

protected ArrayList<ClientScanResult> doInBackground(Void... params) {
    wifiApManager = new WifiApManager(context);  // use the variable here
    return wifiApManager.getClientList(false);
}

protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ClientScanResult> clients){

tv.setText("WifiApState: " + wifiApManager.getWifiApState() + "\n\n");
tv.append("Clients: \n");
for (ClientScanResult clientScanResult : clients) //showin error in clients
    {
        tv.append("####################\n");
        tv.append("IpAddr: " + clientScanResult.getIpAddr() + "\n");
        tv.append("Device: " + clientScanResult.getDevice() + "\n");
        tv.append("HWAddr: " + clientScanResult.getHWAddr() + "\n");
        tv.append("isReachable: " + clientScanResult.isReachable()+ "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can i execute this Method when a Button is Clicked through Onclick Listener

Comment: Yes. You would execute this the same way you did before by calling the execute or executeOnExecutor methods